How do I install avdec_h264 for use with GStreamer in Python on macOS?
I answered my own question How do install gst-python on macOS to work with the recommended GStreamer installers? by using miniconda.
Then I moved on to creating a GStreamer pipeline. But I get an error making an avdec_h264 decoder:
$ GST_DEBUG=3 python3
Python 3.12.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb 16 2024, 20:54:21) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> import sys
>>> import threading
>>> gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
>>> gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
>>> gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
>>> gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
>>> from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo, Gtk, Gdk, GLib, Gio
>>> Gst.init([])
[]
>>> decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264', 'decoder')
0:00:08.230811000 98675 0x600001a94630 WARN     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:765:gst_element_factory_make_valist: no such element factory "avdec_h264"!
>>> decoder == None
True

I successfully installed the following:
conda install gst-plugins-good
conda install libavif
conda install ffmpeg

...but afterward get the same warning and Gst.ElementFactory.make() returns None.
I also tried:
conda install decodebin3
conda install gst-ffmpeg
conda install gst-libav

...but got "…packages are not available from current channels".
How do I install avdec_h264 so the call to Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264', 'decoder') works?

I ran into the same problem when building gstreamer from source, in version  1.24.3
Then I played with meson_options.txt for a bit. I suspect this element is not included by default due to license issues. But anyway, I don't know the specific options I enabled to get this element, maybe this one:
# License-related feature options
option('gpl', type: 'feature', value: 'enabled',
  description: 'Allow build of plugins that have (A)GPL-licensed dependencies')

Modify this to enabled in your meson_options.build, then compile from source again?
Edit
I didn't see this is for Python. In that case, you need some bindings too, which I am not sure are included by default.
